# What does "Torn" mean?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie *Bombshell* (2019), from office, Lilly Balin contacts Megyn Kelly, who was watching her
husband playing tennis:

> Lily Balin: It's a zoo here. The phone's ringing off the hook.
>
> Megyn Kelly: Anyone care he called me a bimbo?
>
> Not really. He tweeted the GQ photo. And?
>
> *(Camera focus on Donald Trump tweet)*
>
> Lilly Balin: **Torn**.

What does "Torn" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Torn to pieces", that is, "emotionally devastated".

The usage is ironic. Lilly is not "torn" at all.